# Only one minus symbol for negative numbers JS regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code `/^[-0-9\b]+(\.\d{0,2})?$/` for the positive and negative numbers validation

It's working fine for the negative numbers(for ex `-12.34`), but user can also type a few "-" symbols(ex: `-12-3-4.12`).

So how can I disable a possibility to type a multiple minus symbols?

Comment: `\b` in a character class matches a backspace character. Are you sure you want it?

Comment: Try `/^-?\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using the regex for liva validation. In these cases, the regex should comprise only optional parts, those that can match an empty string.

You can use

```
/^-?\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BDptHR/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a string
- `-?`  - an optional `-`
- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `\d{0,2}` - 0, 1 or 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

`[-0-9\b]+` Is making it possible to have one or more `-` characters.

Just change your regex to:

```
/^-?[0-9\b]+(\.\d{0,2})?$/
```

Here is the test:

https://regex101.com/r/fbMI7Z/1/

Comment: but now user can't type a negative number at once, he should type a positive one and after go to the beginning of the line and after that type minus

Comment: @mix That's an issue with your Javascript logic. Very rarely is it a good idea to try and fix the user's input as they type. If you really wish to do that then you should look into a comprehensive masking library such as https://imask.js.org/. Standard practice is to just let the user type whatever, check their input onChange, and provide a coherent error message telling them the expected format.